# Estimated Min Max values of ERA5 data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, matplotlib, climate, copernicus

I am working with u and v component of wind on earth engine (ERA5) dataset hourly aggregates as well as directly fetching data from ERA5. 1) What I don't understand is why are u and v component values range from -11.4 to 11.4 and -10.1 to 10.1 respectively? 2) Can I use these ranges to normalize data, like convert to RGB 8 bit values (0-255) eg. 0 maps to -11.4 and 255 for 11.4 for u component and other values in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation for ERA5 on GEE](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/ECMWF_ERA5_LAND_HOURLY):

- `u` refers to the "*Eastward component of the 10m wind. It is the horizontal speed of air moving towards the east, at a height of ten meters above the surface of the Earth, in meters per second.*" and
- `v` to the "*Northward component of the 10m wind. It is the horizontal speed of air moving towards the north, at a height of ten meters above the surface of the Earth, in meters per second.*"

So a value of -11.4 for `u` means the wind is blowing to the west with a speed of 11.4 meters per second.

Yes you can use these values to convert the data to 8 bit values using the formula:

Xnorm = ((X - Xmin) / (Xmax - Xmin)) * 255

Comment: Why is it fixed from -11.4 to 11.4 for u component and -10.1 to 10.1 for v component? Why not some other constant in GEE?

Comment: I dont know how you get those values...

Comment: See ERA5 daily aggregates` u and v component band Min and Max values: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/ECMWF_ERA5_DAILY . It has these ranges that I mentioned above.

Comment: As they say there, those values are just estimations, so you can determine more exact values for your (temporal) domain if you wish... I'm guessing these ranges are centred around 0 so that the colormaps look nice.

Comment: So can we determine/set these Min and Max values by taking the mean of minimum and maximum values of the whole dataset?

Comment: You can determine the maximum value of a dataset by taking the maximum of the whole dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144592/discussion-between-pwnkit-and-bert-coerver).